# É possível ter um sistema operacional com vários kernels?

Tags: sistema-operacional, kernel

Eu estava pensando junto com minha equipe fazer um sistema operacional que rode as aplicações e *drivers* do Windows e Linux, seria usado como base o *kernel* do Linux e do React OS em um *kernel* híbrido, mas eu estou curioso em saber se seria possível ter mais de um *kernel*.

Comment: É possível instalar distribuição GNU/Linux e a seguir instalar o Wine. Desta forma pode rodar também aplicações Windows, além das nativas do sistema operacional base. Há limitações. Wine: https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Se você está perguntando isso você e sua equipe estão longe de fazer um sistema operacional simples, mais ainda um complexo assim. Tenha em mente que ninguém fez isso não por que não tiveram a ideia, mas sim por não ser factível e/ou não traz as vantagens que se espera.

Em tese é possível, mas deve ser extremante difícil e na prática provavelmente precisará de um *kernel* para gerenciar os demais. E nem sei se tem alguma vantagem nisso. Se adicionarem alguma coisa no processador pode ser mais fácil fazer assim. As máquinas virtuais se tornaram "fáceis" de implementar e viável no uso depois que o processador passou ter controle próprio para isto.

Isso vale para qualquer coisa do sistema operacional. Sempre deu para fazer memória virtual, mas só ficou viável quando o processador passou ter mecanismo próprio de controlar isso sem custo para o software.

Teria que se perguntar qual a vantagem de ter vários *kernels*. Provavelmente nenhuma. Quer fazer *drivers* e aplicações diferentes? Ok, faça isso funcionar, não precisa ter mais que um *kernel*. A API do OS nada tem a ver com o *kernel*. Disponibilize APIs diferentes no mesmo *kernel*.

Uma coisa é você desenvolver um sistema operacional com vários *kernels* ou várias APIs, o que na prática não vejo vantagem direta, outra bem diferente é desenvolver um ou mais *kernels* disponibilizando APIs existentes com 100% de compatibilidade.

O ReactOS até hoje não conseguiu 100% de compatibilidade com o Windows XP, e próximo de zero, se eu não estiver desatualizado, com o que foi adicionado no Vista, 7, 8, 10 e 11. Inclusive os *drivers* dele são incompatíveis com os *drivers* atuais do Windows.

Se fosse fácil, ou mesmo factível, o Linux teria dado compatibilidade com os *drivers* do Windows, isso teria dado um salto na sua adoção. Não deixaram de fazer porque não tiveram a ideia ou faltou vontade de ter feito.

Compatibilizar aplicativos já é um pouco mais fácil, mesmo assim precisa esforço e muita competência. A Microsoft investiu nos seus melhores engenheiros, e boa parte dos melhores do mundo trabalham lá, e conseguiram fazer duas coisas: conseguiram disponibilizar a API de usuário do Linux no Windows, então hoje "qualquer" aplicação Linux roda no Windows nativamente; e fizeram o SQL Server que é muito integrado com o Windows rodar no Linux integralmente, sem modificações (estão fazendo modificações para otimizações), e isso abre a possibilidade de quase qualquer aplicação Windows poder rodar no Linux. Ou seja, ainda não está 100% madura, mas já existe o que deseja.

O que está se fazendo hoje em dia é usar máquinas virtuais completas ou não para rodar mais de um sistema operacional na mesma máquina ao mesmo tempo e se comunicarem de tal forma que seja quase transparente quando está rodando uma aplicação no Windows, Linux ou outro OS, apesar que só um deles é o *host* e os demais são *guests*. O próprio Windows tem tecnologia que faz isso para rodar aplicações antigas que não rodam mais nas versões mais novas.

Outro dia vi um grupo de pessoas que se propuseram fazer um sistema operacional livre de *bugs*. É muita ingenuidade achar que os outros erram porque são burros, preguiçosos, sem criatividade, ou coisa do tipo. Se não fizeram é porque, no mínimo, não vale o esforço.

Eu acho que com o hardware atual na prática vai acabar fazendo o que já existe. O melhor que daria é fazer um *nanokernel* que fique disponível para os demais *kernels* trabalharem.

Comment: Você disse sobre um tipo de virtualização onde se comunica de tal forma ao sistema operacional base que é uma interação quase transparente, como se chama?

Comment: Sei lá, acho que não tem nome específico

Comment: Eu perguntei sobre fazer um sistema operacional com vários kernels pq cada um teria o trabalho de processar a informação de cada sistema operacional correspondente como um kernel pra rodar aplicação só pra Windows e outro só pra Linux

Comment: Talvez seja melhor fazer vários kernels virtuais?

Comment: Isso não faz sentido, *kernel* não é o que provavelmente você está achando que é, conforme eu já demonstrei na resposta.

Comment: Um kernel seria melhor se fosse desenvolvido em C ou Assembly direito?

Comment: Isso é irrelevante, na verdade algum mínimo Assembly tem que ter, o resto é decisão de cada um, e é uma decisão simples, a quantidade de decisões que precisa tomar quando se faz um *kernel* e a complexidade delas não se compara com essa decisão.

Comment: Pra essa situação qual tipo de kernel vc recomendaria (Microkernel ou monolitico)?

Comment: Não dá para responder isso assim e já está fugindo do foco da pergunta, veja o [tour].